# Keras model gets worse when fine-tuning

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning, pre-trained-model

I'm trying to follow the fine-tuning steps described in https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning#create_the_base_model_from_the_pre-trained_convnets to get a trained model for binary segmentation.

I create an encoder-decoder with the weights of the encoder being the ones of the MobileNetV2 and fixed as `encoder.trainable = False`. Then, I define my decoder as said in the tutorial and I train the network for  300 epochs using a learning rate of 0.005. I get the following loss value and Jaccard index during the lasts epochs:

```
Epoch 297/300
55/55 [==============================] - 85s 2s/step - loss: 0.2443 - jaccard_sparse3D: 0.5556 - accuracy: 0.9923 - val_loss: 0.0440 - val_jaccard_sparse3D: 0.3172 - val_accuracy: 0.9768
Epoch 298/300
55/55 [==============================] - 75s 1s/step - loss: 0.2437 - jaccard_sparse3D: 0.5190 - accuracy: 0.9932 - val_loss: 0.0422 - val_jaccard_sparse3D: 0.3281 - val_accuracy: 0.9776
Epoch 299/300
55/55 [==============================] - 78s 1s/step - loss: 0.2465 - jaccard_sparse3D: 0.4557 - accuracy: 0.9936 - val_loss: 0.0431 - val_jaccard_sparse3D: 0.3327 - val_accuracy: 0.9769
Epoch 300/300
55/55 [==============================] - 85s 2s/step - loss: 0.2467 - jaccard_sparse3D: 0.5030 - accuracy: 0.9923 - val_loss: 0.0463 - val_jaccard_sparse3D: 0.3315 - val_accuracy: 0.9740
```

I store all the weights of this model and then, I compute the fine-tuning with the following steps:

```py
model.load_weights('my_pretrained_weights.h5')
model.trainable = True
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.00001, name='adam'),
                  loss=SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                  metrics=[jaccard, "accuracy"])
model.fit(training_generator, validation_data=(val_x, val_y), epochs=5,
                validation_batch_size=2, callbacks=callbacks)
```

Suddenly the performance of my model is way much worse than during the training of the decoder:

```
Epoch 1/5
55/55 [==============================] - 89s 2s/step - loss: 0.2417 - jaccard_sparse3D: 0.0843 - accuracy: 0.9946 - val_loss: 0.0079 - val_jaccard_sparse3D: 0.0312 - val_accuracy: 0.9992
Epoch 2/5
55/55 [==============================] - 90s 2s/step - loss: 0.1920 - jaccard_sparse3D: 0.1179 - accuracy: 0.9927 - val_loss: 0.0138 - val_jaccard_sparse3D: 7.1138e-05 - val_accuracy: 0.9998
Epoch 3/5
55/55 [==============================] - 95s 2s/step - loss: 0.2173 - jaccard_sparse3D: 0.1227 - accuracy: 0.9932 - val_loss: 0.0171 - val_jaccard_sparse3D: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.9999
Epoch 4/5
55/55 [==============================] - 94s 2s/step - loss: 0.2428 - jaccard_sparse3D: 0.1319 - accuracy: 0.9927 - val_loss: 0.0190 - val_jaccard_sparse3D: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 5/5
55/55 [==============================] - 97s 2s/step - loss: 0.1920 - jaccard_sparse3D: 0.1107 - accuracy: 0.9926 - val_loss: 0.0215 - val_jaccard_sparse3D: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
```

Is there any known reason why this is happening? Is it normal?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: do not do model.compile after you load the weights

Comment: If I do not recompile the model, then `model.trainable=True` doesn't do anything in the layers that are supposed to be trainable now. I checked it experimentally and it is also said in https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning#un-freeze_the_top_layers_of_the_model "you should recompile the model (necessary for these changes to take effect),". Compiling the model also allows me to change the learning rate for example. The other problem is that the weights should be loaded before doing `model.trainable=True`  as they come from a model that had some layers frozen.

Comment: Did not know that thanks for the info. I will give it a test as well.

Answer (score 2):

OK I found out what I do different that makes it NOT necessary to compile. I do not set encoder.trainable = False. What I do in the code below is equivalent

```
for layer in encoder.layers:
    layer.trainable=False
```

then train your model. Then you can unfreeze the encoder weights with

```
for layer in encoder.layers:
    layer.trainable=True
```

You do not need to recompile the model. I tested this and it works as expected. You can
verify by priniting model summary before and after and look at the number of trainable parameters. As for changing the learning rate I find it is best to use the the keras callback ReduceLROnPlateau to automatically adjust the learning rate based on validation loss. I also recommend using the EarlyStopping callback which monitors validation and halts training if the loss fails to reduce after 'patience' number of consecutive epochs. Setting restore_best_weights=True will load the weights for the epoch with the lowest validation loss so you don't have to save then reload the weights. Set epochs to a large number to ensure this callback activates. The code I use is shown below

```
es=tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping( monitor="val_loss", patience=3,
                                     verbose=1,  restore_best_weights=True)
rlronp=tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau( monitor="val_loss", factor=0.5, patience=1,
                                             verbose=1)
callbacks=[es, rlronp]
```

In model.fit set callbacks=callbacks

Comment: Thanks! I'll check this one out and see if it works. When doing my `encoder.trainable=True`, the number of trainable parameters increased as you suggested but, after some epochs, the weights belonging to the `encoder`, didn't get updated. However, when doing `model.compile`, they do get updated. That's why I think I really need to compile it. Also, I want to dramatically reduce my learning rate when fixing the encoder as trainable, which is different from using ReduceLROnPlateau.